# Python HTTP Server unable to send response inside Windows Service

Tags: python, windows-services, pywin32

I've written a simple HTTP server and made it into a Windows service using pywin32. The server successfully processes requests when run in the debugger, inside actual service it gets the request but hangs on send_response operation. What might be the reason?

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import sys

PORT_NUMBER = 6363

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("Hello World !", "utf-8"))
        return

class TestSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestSvc"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"
    _svc_description_ = "Tests server inside service."

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        print('Started httpserver on port ', PORT_NUMBER)
        self.server.serve_forever()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.server.shutdown()

#sys.frozen = 'windows_exe'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestSvc, argv=sys.argv)
```

Comment: Running as admin? Might be an issue with privileges

Comment: pythonservice.exe is set to run as administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it was hanging when executing sys.stderr.write (which is the default logging output for BaseHTTPRequestHandler). So I've overridden log_message function in my request handler class and it works fine now.